# Что означают эти элементы? [C++]

Tags: c++

```
%{ /// <- Зачем это
#include <stdio.h>
double * array;
extern char * yytext;
#define YYSTYPE double /// Что это?
%} /// <- Зачем это
%token NUMBER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' /// <- Что это значит?
%% /// <- Зачем это
body:  expr '\n' { fprintf(stderr, "%lf\n", $1); }
    | body expr '\n' { fprintf(stderr, "%lf\n", $2); }
    ;

expr: NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
    | '-' expr { $$ = -$2; }
    | expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
    | '{' NUMBER '}' { $$ = array[(int)($2)];}
    ;
%%

int yyerror(const char * a)
{
    return 0;
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    double ff[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    array = &ff[0];
    while (yyparse());
}
```

Что значит %, %%, |, expr, expr:, body:?
P.S Гуглил, но толком ничего путного не нашел

Comment: Садя по всему тут какой-то конечный автомат записан тут (грамматика). Может какие специальные дефайны это обрабатывают.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выглядит, как [yacc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc). Yacc компилирует грамматики, записанные в нотации Бэкуса-Наура в парсеры на `c`. И синтаксис грамматик там именно такой. То есть это не `c++`, а `c` и `yacc`: `yacc` примет на вход этот файл и выдаст программу на `c`.

См.:

- http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/
- http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/algol/lex-yacc-howto.html
- http://lib.ru/MAN/DEMOS210/yacc.txt

Comment: вот же: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html

Answer (score 3):

Это файл описания синтаксического анализатора для YACC. К C++ никакого отношения не имеет. Касательно "что значит" - вам в документацию по YACC.